# How can I obtain a tax exemption certificate for a sign company that is located outside of the united states?

Tags: taxes, tax-exemption

How can I obtain a tax exemption certificate for a sign company that is located outside of the united states. I have been purchasing machines for my print shop and they are being delivered directly to the freight forwarder to leave the country but I am still having to pay taxes.

What can I do to avoid paying the tax?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance. You should probably talk to a tax adviser in the country where you seek exemption.

Comment: Duly noted. It was a question.

Comment: @keshlam Nope. For example, in NC you file [Form E-599C, Purchaser’s Affidavit of Export](https://www.ncdor.gov/taxes-forms/sales-and-use-tax/sales-and-use-tax-forms-and-certificates/exemption-certificates/form-e-599c-purchasers-affidavit-export).

Comment: @keshlam There's no federal sales tax, so it's irrelevant. State sales tax is generally exempted for foreign exports, see also [California](https://www.cdtfa.ca.gov/formspubs/pub104/#Sales). For that matter, state sales tax isn't applied on purchases that are exported to a different state; you pay the destination state's sales tax.

Comment: Comment withdrawn, then.